# Script not running in selenium 4.12.0 showing HasInputDevice error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, slf4j

I changed my scripts for the issue of HasInputDevice interface methods
Because of chromedriver 117, my scripts are not running.
I changed my selenium version 3.141.59 to 4.12.0 to solve this issue
But now, HasInputDevice interface method issues are coming.
I don't know, how to solve this
please help
And some places showing compatibility error
I used the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>AIM</groupId>
    <artifactId>Aim</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Aim</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
    <cucumber.version>6.9.0</cucumber.version>
    <serenity.version>2.4.48</serenity.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>2.4.48</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>
    <!-- Dependencies and other sections here -->
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to use selenium 4.12.0. After that my scripts are launching the chrome itself.
Console error:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
12:03:55.789 [main] INFO  i.c.core.plugin.SerenityReporter - Running feature from file:///D:/Git/AIMe2e/src/test/resources/DealerAndIndirectFeatures/DRE_DealerAndIndirect.feature
12:03:55.794 [main] WARN  i.c.core.plugin.SerenityReporter - Feature from file:///D:/Git/AIMe2e/src/test/resources/DealerAndIndirectFeatures/DRE_DealerAndIndirect.feature is not under the 'features' directory. Requirements report will not be correctly generated!
testrunner.MyTestRunnerDirect_DealerAndIndirectcom.google.inject.ProvisionException: 
Unable to provision, see the following errors:
1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices
  at WebdriverCloseBrowser.<init>(WebdriverCloseBrowser.java:22)
  while locating WebdriverCloseBrowser
  at WebDriverModule.configure(WebDriverModule.java:20)
  while locating CloseBrowser
Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_INJECTING_CONSTRUCTOR
1 error
======================
Full classname legend:
======================
CloseBrowser:          "net.thucydides.core.webdriver.CloseBrowser"
WebDriverModule:       "net.thucydides.core.guice.webdriver.WebDriverModule"
WebdriverCloseBrowser: "net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebdriverCloseBrowser"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================
[INFO] Running Direct-Ordering and delivery
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in Direct-Ordering and delivery
[INFO] Running Direct-Stock Booking and Report Generation
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in Direct-Stock Booking and Report Generation
[INFO] Running dealer indirect Scenario verification #3
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in dealer indirect Scenario verification #3
[INFO] Running Direct-Configuration and Assortment&Inventory page validation
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in Direct-Configuration and Assortment&Inventory page validation
[INFO] Running Drivus brand selection and validation
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in Drivus brand selection and validation
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There is no solution for this, coz many of the inbuilt selenium defined methods are only support to the 3.14 only, So I advocate you that again you have to switch back the 4.12 to 3.14. else if you want to continue with 4.12, build your code from scratch.